# Extend Query to include additional column

Tags: join, ms-access

I have the following query, which gives me (in addition to other columns) the Direction ID only:

```
SELECT Users.Name, Users.Surname, Transactions.Timestamp, AccessPoints.Description as Door, Readers.Direction
    FROM (Readers INNER JOIN (AccessPoints INNER JOIN Points_Readers ON AccessPoints.PointID = Points_Readers.PointID)
    ON Readers.ReaderID = Points_Readers.ReaderID) INNER JOIN (Transactions INNER JOIN (AccessNumbers INNER JOIN Users
    ON AccessNumbers.AccessNumberID = Users.AccessNumberID) ON Transactions.Number = AccessNumbers.Number)
    ON Readers.ReaderID = Transactions.ReaderID
    WHERE (Transactions.Timestamp>#2018-08-15  06:50:16#) ORDER BY Transactions.Timestamp;
```

What I want to do is extend the query to include `Directions.DirectionsText` by joining `Readers.Direction` to `Directions` ON `Directions.Direction`. I'm having trouble with exactly where to place the join so that I don't keep getting errors in the `FROM` clause. (I still haven't figured out how to get `INNER JOIN` clauses working with Access' need to use parentheses for joins.)

The columns in `Directions` are `Direction` (numeric) and `DirectionText` (String)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm having trouble with exactly where to place the join

Directions is joined to Readers - so you must place it adjacent to this table enclosind this pair in additional parenthesis:

```
SELECT Users.Name, 
       Users.Surname, 
       Transactions.Timestamp, 
       AccessPoints.Description as Door, 
       Readers.Direction,
       Directions.DirectionsText
FROM ( ( Readers 
         INNER JOIN 
         Directions ON Readers.Direction = Directions.Direction
       )
       INNER JOIN 
       ( AccessPoints 
         INNER JOIN 
         Points_Readers ON AccessPoints.PointID = Points_Readers.PointID
       ) ON Readers.ReaderID = Points_Readers.ReaderID
     ) 
     INNER JOIN 
     ( Transactions 
       INNER JOIN 
       ( AccessNumbers 
         INNER JOIN 
         Users ON AccessNumbers.AccessNumberID = Users.AccessNumberID
       ) ON Transactions.Number = AccessNumbers.Number
     ) ON Readers.ReaderID = Transactions.ReaderID
WHERE (Transactions.Timestamp>#2018-08-15  06:50:16#) 
ORDER BY Transactions.Timestamp;
```

> that I don't keep getting errors in the FROM clause

Build the query text using Query Builder - it always creates correct code or produce error message if there are any logical problems.

Or (if you want write query text "by hands" without using the master) rewrite the query to cartesian form (with comma-separated tables list and all joining conditions in WHERE clause) - it do not need the accuracy in parenthessis:

```
SELECT Users.Name, 
       Users.Surname, 
       Transactions.Timestamp, 
       AccessPoints.Description as Door, 
       Readers.Direction,
       Directions.DirectionsText
FROM Readers, 
     AccessPoints, 
     Points_Readers,
     Transactions, 
     AccessNumbers,
     Users,
     Directions 
WHERE AccessPoints.PointID = Points_Readers.PointID
  AND Readers.ReaderID = Points_Readers.ReaderID
  AND AccessNumbers.AccessNumberID = Users.AccessNumberID
  AND Transactions.Number = AccessNumbers.Number
  AND Readers.ReaderID = Transactions.ReaderID
  AND Readers.Direction = Directions.Direction
  AND Transactions.Timestamp>#2018-08-15 06:50:16#
ORDER BY Transactions.Timestamp;
```

The order of either tables in FROM clause or conditions in WHERE clause does not matter in those form.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. However, when I run that query, I receive error messages of "Parameter object is imporoperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided." (MDB Viewer Plus) OR "Too Few Parameters. Expected 1." (Java 7's MS Access MDB driver). MS Access (Office 365) asks me for the value of `Directions.DirectionsText` instead of displaying a resultSet with that value.

Comment: *MS Access (Office 365) asks me for the value of Directions.DirectionsText* Check text for misprintings.